# SDL2 and OpenGL: flickering with double buffering, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: opengl, shaders, sdl2, double-buffering

I'm currently fiddling with SDL2 and OpenGL to get an understanding on how they work and, moreover, how shaders are done and work.
Right now, I'm following [this tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Shaders), using SDL instead of glfw; and in a SDL window I render 2 triangles via shader and change their color dynamically, but an obnoxious flickering effect shows, even though I'm sure double buffering is active.

Now, to the code:

```
    //Here they are SDL attributes for OpenGL
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1 );
    //Double buffer should be on by default, but I set it anyway
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

    //SDL window creation
    mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Window Title", 
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
                            mWidth, 
                            mHeight, 
                            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );

    // Use Vsync    
   if( SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval( 1 ) < 0 )
   {
         SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
  }


    //OpenGL initialization
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
```

while one of the shaders (no point in pasting the other one, too, as the issue is the same) I use is:

vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
out vec3 LSampleFrag;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    LSampleFrag = color;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330
out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 LSampleFrag;
void main()
{
    color = LSampleFrag;
}
```

Binding of vertex data to the shader:

```
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    //VBO data
    GLfloat vertexData[] =
    {
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &gVBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

and its render function is this one, where I change, everytime is called shade of green:

```
GLfloat timeValue = SDL_GetTicks();
GLfloat greenValue = (sin(timeValue) / 2) + 0.5;
GLint vertexColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(mProgramID, "LSampleFrag");
glUniform4f(vertexColorLocation, 0.0f, greenValue, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glBindVertexArray(gVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);

//in the main render function, after rendering the shader
SDL_GL_SwapWindow( window_->getSDLWindow());
```

As I've already said, double buffering is active but flickering is still an issue: am I missing something? I really don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact it's not a flickering problem, in the last codebox lies the root of the nuisance.

```
GLfloat timeValue = SDL_GetTicks();
GLfloat greenValue = (sin(timeValue) / 2) + 0.5;
```

Those two lines update the green value each millisecond, changing the colour far too fast, and it could look like a flicker, try increasing the period (decreasing the frequency) of the sin like this:

```
float period = 1000.0f;
GLfloat timeValue = SDL_GetTicks();
GLfloat greenValue = (sin(timeValue/period) / 2) + 0.5;
```